# How to create a filename with the current date and time in python when query is ran

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.4, python-3.6

When I run my query below, it creates a file called ‘mycsvfile’. However is there a way to add the current date and timestamp when the CSV file is created? For example if I run this query now the file should be named mycsvfile20171012 – 10:00:00 (something like that).

Could someone edit my code and show me how to do this please?

My code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

# Replace the following Query with your own Elastic Search Query
res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["DTDT", "TRDT", "SPLE", "RPLE"],
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"wildcard": {"CN": "TEST1"}}

                            ]
                        }
                    }
}, size=10)



header_names = { 'DTDT': 'DATE', 'TRDT': 'TIME', ...}

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source'] 
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writerow(header_names)  # will write DATE, TIME, ... in correct place
            header_present = True


        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module, specifically functions [`datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) and [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is better to use underscore in filename than any other special character since it widely accepted
Therefore constructing file name as below :

```
csv_file = 'myfile_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.csv'
```

Use datetime as below :

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

# Replace the following Query with your own Elastic Search Query
res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["DTDT", "TRDT", "SPLE", "RPLE"],
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"wildcard": {"CN": "TEST1"}}

                            ]
                        }
                    }
}, size=10)

from datetime import datetime
import os

file_path = <PASS YOUR FILE HERE>

csv_file = 'myfile_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')) + '.csv'

csv_file_full = os.path.join(file_path, os.sep, csv_file)

header_names = { 'DTDT': 'DATE', 'TRDT': 'TIME', ...}

with open(csv_file_full, 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source']
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writerow(header_names)  # will write DATE, TIME, ... in correct place
            header_present = True


        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Comment: Hi Dinesh, i am getting the below error when i use your method - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/test1.py", line 28, in <module>
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'myfile_2017-10-12_10:31:12.csv'

Comment: thank you dinesh! that worked but im just wondering is there is another way to format the name of the file. for example right now the format is - mycsvfile2017-10-12_10_35_13. Is there a way to  have mycsvfile2017-10-12_10:35:13

Comment: @DineshPundkar: down vote was for the invalid filename and lack of explanation, but you've fixed the former, so down vote removed.

Comment: @Rich - It is better to use underscore in filename than any other special character since it widely accepted

Comment: @Dniesh, thanks for helping me out again! I do appreciate it! you might see more posts from me soon haha! thanks

Comment: @Dniesh, how can i specify where i want the file to be saved within the updated code you just given me? for example if i want to place this file on my desktop..how would i do that. would it be like path='....' ?

Comment: when i use the updated of your code and enter my path for example file_path = 'C:/Users/Rich/Desktop' - the code runs but it does not appear on my desktop. any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156540/discussion-between-dinesh-pundkar-and-rich).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do like this:
However ":" is not supported in filenames so 20171010–10.00.00

```
>>> import time
>>> fname = lambda : "mycsvfile{}.csv".format(time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H.%M.%S"))
>>> 
>>> fname()
'mycsvfile20171012-17.24.59.csv'

>>> with open(fname()) as f:
>>>    pass
```

Comment: where would i put this in my code? code you show me please

Comment: you put it where you open the file

Comment: @Silencer you should add .csv to the format and show him an example.

Comment: Ok, I have modified it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a variable for file name as `file_name` and use `datetime.now()`

```
from datetime import datetime
file_name = 'mycsvfile' + str(datetime.now()) + '.csv'
```